# jQuery UI Drag + drop after AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I'm using a AJAX call to create a new droppable box. Now within that box I want to create another droppable container after a successful drag and drop event into that box. I don't want to create a recursive call, however.

```
 $("#box").click(
      function (e)
      {
         // Create container 
         // Create addDrop droppable first container (with class .droppable)
      });
      });

function addDrop(){
            $(".droppable").droppable({
                /* blah */
                drop: create new droppable container ?
                });
         });
```

What would be the best way to create containers that are droppable after an AJAX call?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you create these in "onSuccess" callback of your AJAX call